# App freezes with SecTrustEvaluate [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Error

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

When I deploy and start my app it freezes on a white screen and I see the following errors in my device log:

```
Jun  7 11:21:42 device-inno10 profiled[130] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Jun  7 11:21:42 device-inno10 profiled[130] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
Jun  7 11:21:42 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:21:50 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:21:57 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:05 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:12 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:20 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:27 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:35 device-inno10 syslogd[25] <Notice>: ASL Sender Statistics
Jun  7 11:22:35 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:42 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jun  7 11:22:50 device-inno10 installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
```

Sometimes it stays frozen so long that the app is not able to start at all. I have the same issue on all my devices, even the newer ones.

In the Apple Dev Forum it was suggested to delete all provisioning profiles from the device however that didn't work for me. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you reboot the device after removing all the profiles?

Comment: Did provisioning profiles get added back somehow (MDM, running multiple biulds)? Can you show the provisioning profiles list for the device in question.  Those errors (specifically the number you are getting, point to having multiple provisioning profiles on the device.  If you did clear them out, I don't know why you would still be seeing so many errors.

Comment: @wottle  
No the the profiles are not added back. I tried it several times. But then I noticed some other weird issue. I then tried to add the profile manually. Seems like I am not able to install provisioning profiles on my test devices. Neither via XCode->Window->Devices nor via Apple Configurator. Also when I run my app - via XCode no provisioning profile is installed on the device. The device log says: `Jun 9 07:40:37 device-inno07 profiled[128] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...` but nothing happens.

Comment: @wottl My test devices are behind a proxy and are configured by our IT security team. They also contain no SIM card (but I dont think that this matters). When I try to install the profile on my private device, everything seems OK.

Comment: Odd.  Our test devices are configured in a similar way (proxy that doesn't allow connection to Apple servers) and I haven't seen the issue where profiles can't be installed.  Not having a connection to Apple can cause other problems, specifically with the trust of an enterprise provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that iOS makes HTTP calls to the akamai and the Apple network, that execute randomly and / or specifically before any app starts.

Following URLs are called with HTTP:

- http://init-p01md.apple.com/bag (contains APNS specific infos)
- http://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_AppleKeyServicesCRL/com_apple_MobileAsset_AppleKeyServicesCRL.xml (Seems to be a certificate revocation list)

Because I am developing in a high security environment, we block HTTP calls on our firewall and therefore the HTTP calls ran into a timeout. This in turn caused a very slow app which took about 10 seconds.

After modifying the firewall rules to allow these 2 calls - everything works as expected again.